# jquery How to show maxlength limit after maxlength complete

Tags: jquery

I need to show maxlength validation after entering the last character in input type.for ex if limit is 10 then i need to show error message when typed 11 character.

```
if(maxLength > parseInt(localStorage.getItem('max'+field.id)))
    {

        console.log("Yes true");
    }

      if (curLength == maxLength)  
    {   console.log("wwww");

        extraOne = parseInt(maxLength)+parseInt(1); 
        $(field).attr("maxlength",extraOne);

    }
```

This is js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/php_web_dev/opcasrk9/11/

Comment: dud you already shown an error when limit exceeds https://gyazo.com/39eb58697595eddc4a1fbb0175f334d2

Answer (score 0):

You have added maxlength property sets to 10 in HTML, which means that you cant type more than 10 characters. Hence this validation cant be performed.

Answer (score 0):

One sollution you can consider is to allow a max length of 11 and when the user exceeds the limit remove the last (eleventh) character and show the message.

```js
$(".limit-char").on('keyup',function(event) {      
    var maxLength = $( this ).attr( "maxlength" );
    var curLength = $( this ).val().length;
 var fieldError = "#error1";
  
    if (maxLength <= curLength)  
    {    
        var curLength = $( this ).val().length; 
        $(fieldError).text("Limit Exceed");
        $( this ).val($( this ).val().substring(0, maxLength-1));
    }else {
        $(this).css('background','none');
        $(fieldError).text("");
    }         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="limit-char" type="text" maxlength="11" />
<span id="error1"></span>
```

Comment: but i want to set it on character limit 10

Comment: You asked for a sollution that shows the message when the 11th character is typed. So you have to allow 11 characters. That's what my demo does (keeping ofcourse only the 10 first characters)

Comment: Its working now i have added maxlength dynamically to all input fields and the remove last character from imput values.